# Find all children of parent class and render to JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have a controller to fetch projects and related topics and return a JSON response.

My Projects controller:

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController

  def get_projects
    @projects = Project.find(:all, :limit => 8)
    render :json => @projects
  end

end
```

Each Project has multiple topics and I need to get these topics before sending them via JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I needed to was call the method on the render. It looks like this now

```
  def get_projects
    @projects = Project.find(:all, :limit => 8)
    render :json => @projects.to_json(:methods => [:banner_image_url, :topics])
  end
```

Comment: Glad you found a solution. I would also add ", :includes => [:topics]) to your Project.find call. This is called eager loading and avoids DB lookups later.

Comment: What version of Rails are you using? Because much of this code is deprecated in Rails 4 and even Rails 3.2.

Comment: @Mohamad this is an old Rails 3.1 app. Just extending some features before they sunset it next year at some point.

Comment: @Midwire Thanks! I'll do that.